# Printing a list in tabular format using loop

Tags: python, list, loops, format, tabular

Looking how to get my list such as,

```
myList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9"]
```

into a tabular format like,

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

I would prefer using a loop to automate it so that it picks the first 3 items from the list and then moves the next 3 onto the next row and so on. I found similar problems but couldn't find out how to implement it into my program, I am just a beginner in python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Below, we enumerate myList, and we print a newline every 3 characters.

```
for j, i in enumerate(myList):
    if j%3==0:
        print('\n')
    print(i, end= " ")
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6 

7 8 9
```

Comment: The answer was super helpful, I am only having problems with formatting now.
Say one of the numbers was 3 digits such as '100' instead of single digit '8' how would I get them to all line up?